# CodeHS keyboard input not found

Tags: python, keyboard

I am trying to get the input for any other key other than the arrow keys on CodeHS. I'm looking for the 'E' key, but I can't find any documentation or other posts, so maybe I'm just stupid.
I've tried stuff like

```
if e.key == "E
if e.key == Keyboard.E
etc.
```

I know there is an `input()` function, but that is for a text prompt, I just want raw detection. CodeHS uses their weird libraries, so I don't know if I can get it the same way as on an IDE.

Code that I am using the key detection for:
from browser import timer

```
cursor = Rectangle(10, 20)`
screen = []`
textlist = []`
boole = [True] 
username = "EDOS"

def init_screen():
    background = Rectangle(get_width(), get_height())
    screen.append(background)
    txt = Text("Welcome to EdOS")
    txt.set_font("12pt Courier New")
    txt.set_color(Color.white)
    txt.set_position(0, 12)
    usertext = Text(f"{username}@EdPC:/$")
    usertext.set_font("10pt Courier New")
    usertext.set_position(0, get_height() - 10)
    usertext.set_color(Color.white)
    screen.append(usertext)
    screen.append(txt)
    print(screen)


def add_screen():
    screen_copy = screen.copy()
    for i in range(len(screen_copy)):
        add(screen_copy[i])
        if type(screen_copy[i]) == Text:
            item = screen_copy[i]
            screen.remove(item)
            textlist.append(item)


def init_text_input():
    cursor.set_color(Color.white)
    cursor.set_position(get_width() / 5+15, get_height() - 25)
    add(cursor)


def blink_cursor(boole):
    if boole[0]:
        cursor.set_color(Color.white)
    else:
        cursor.set_color(Color.black)

def input_callback():
    key = e.key
    
def timer_to_blinker():
    boole[0] = not boole[0]
    blink_cursor(boole)
    
def input_handler(e):
    if e.key == "ArrowLeft":
        print("Left Arrow key pressed.")
    if e.key == "ArrowRight":
        print("Right Arrow key pressed.")
    if e.key == "ArrowUp":
        print("Up Arrow key pressed.")
    if e.key == "ArrowDown":
        print("Down Arrow key pressed.")
    if e.key == "E":
        print("E key")
def kernel():
    init_screen()
    add_screen()
    init_text_input()
    

init_text_input()
timer_id = timer.set_interval(timer_to_blinker, 500) 

kernel()
add_key_down_handler(input_handler)
add_key_down_handler(input_callback)`
```

I tried everything I could, there is **ZERO** documentation on detecting keys on codeHS python outside of the arrow keys. afaik

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **keyboard** library. FYI it will require root permission on linux.

```
import keyboard

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
        print("Yes, 'a' is pressed")
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to get the keycode by using

```
print(e.key)
```

however, the official documentation tells nothing about the other keys.
[Documentation](https://codehs.com/documentation/new/brython-graphics)

```
from browser import timer
cursor = Rectangle(10, 20)
screen = []
textlist = []
x = 0
boole = [True] 
username = "chud"
at = "@"
hostname = "EdPC"
signifier = ":/$" 
atlen = (at.count('')-1)
userlen = (username.count('')-1)
hostlen = (hostname.count('')-1)
inputtext = Text("")
signifierlen = (signifier.count('')-1)
def init_screen():
    background = Rectangle(get_width(), get_height())
    screen.append(background)
    txt = Text("Welcome to E-DOS")
    txt.set_font("12pt Courier New")
    txt.set_color(Color.white)
    txt.set_position(0, 12)
    usertext = Text(f"{username}{at}{hostname}{signifier}")
    usertext.set_font("10pt Courier New")
    usertext.set_position(0, get_height() - 10)
    usertext.set_color(Color.white)
    screen.append(usertext)
    screen.append(txt)
    
    inputtext.set_position(get_height()-25,20)
    inputtext.set_color(Color.white)
    inputtext.set_font("10pt Courier New")
    screen.append(inputtext)
    print(screen)
    
def add_screen():
    screen_copy = screen.copy()
    for i in range(len(screen_copy)):
        add(screen_copy[i])
        if type(screen_copy[i]) == Text:
            item = screen_copy[i]
            screen.remove(item)
            textlist.append(item)


def init_cursor():
    cursor.set_color(Color.white)
    cursor.set_position(((hostlen+userlen+signifierlen)*9), get_height() - 25)
    add(cursor)
    print(8.3*(hostlen+userlen+signifierlen))
    print()
    
def blink_cursor(boole):
    if boole[0]:
        cursor.set_color(Color.white)
    else:
        cursor.set_color(Color.black)

def input_callback():
    key = e.key
    
def timer_to_blinker():
    boole[0] = not boole[0]
    blink_cursor(boole)
print(inputtext)
def input_handler(e):
        print(e.key)
        #Control, Shift, CapsLock, Tab, `, Escape, Backspace, Enter, Alt 
        print("inputtext:",inputtext)
        inputtext = Text(f"{e.key}")
        print(inputtext.text)
        if e.key == "ArrowLeft":
            print("Left Arrow key pressed.")
        if e.key == "ArrowRight":
            print("Right Arrow key pressed.")
        if e.key == "ArrowUp":
            print("Up Arrow key pressed.")
        if e.key == "ArrowDown":
            print("Down Arrow key pressed.")
        
def input_to_text():
    inputtext.set_position(cursor)
def kernel():
    init_screen()
    add_screen()
    init_cursor()
    


timer_id = timer.set_interval(timer_to_blinker, 500)

kernel()
add_key_down_handler(input_handler)
add_key_down_handler(input_callback)
```

Answer (score -1):

There’s a module called ‘keyboard’ in Python which can be used for detecting key presses. To use it you need to first install it using:

```
pip install keyboard
```

Then to use the module:

```
#Import the module
import keyboard

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("e"):
        #some code
```

Note that we have used a while loop here because if we don’t use it, then the program will get executed instantly without giving us a chance to press the ‘e’ key. The while loop keeps the program running for us to press the key.

Since you want to detect if any key other than the arrows keys are pressed, you can use the following code:

```
#Import the module 
import keyboard

while True:
    #Detect and identify the key press
    event = keyboard.read_event()
   
    if event.event_type == keyboard.KEY_DOWN:
        #Check which key was pressed
        if event.name != "up" and event.name != "down" and event.name != "left" and event.name != "right":
            #some code
```

AFAIK, to use the ‘keyboard’ module on Linux, you need to root it.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "https://static1.codehs.com/gulp/2f60c77c9741ba2198347d2fd2e701991d2ee737/abacus/evaluation/brython-graphics-3-11-1.html?canvasHeight=480&canvasWidth=400&abacusUID=37417&parentOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fcodehs.com&iframeID=browser-runner-37417#__main__", line 4, in <module>
    import keyboard
ModuleNotFoundError: keyboard



with codeHS' weird libraries, they don't have keyboard i think

Comment: @Soldrion I don’t have any experience with codeHS. Does it have any  terminal of sorts?

Comment: yes, it has a terminal, but it uses some weird proprietary library, with documentation pages. However, it does not have documentation about keys other than the arrowkeys, leading me to believe that it does not support it. This is unfortunate, as I have tried to make games with movement and other functions that need other keys before and have been stumped by the same issue. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m4vj4vT35veWE6-pbn_AKBKHtrhJObt9/view?usp=sharing video of me on project

Comment: @Soldrion I'd suggest that you try on some software other than CodeHS. Also, can you provide a link to the documentation about the proprietary library?

Comment: see my answer on the post